# Vector-Lattices and "Approximating $\mathscr{L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)}$".

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, category-theory, lebesgue-integral, vector-lattices

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654427/category-theory-and-lebesgue-integration) I asked whether $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$ forms a category in any way. It was concluded that indeed it does not.

I thought to myself, "well, could we at least *approximate* the space with a category?" I couldn't see any obvious reason why not. It then occurred to me to ask, "what properties of $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$ might I want to preserve if I try to approximate $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$ with a category?"

So I had a look around and stumbled on vector-lattices (which are defined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space)). They appear to have many of the properties I was interested in in the question I provided a link to above. So:

> Do vector-lattices form a category $\mathcal{C}$? Is $\mathscr{L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)}$ a vector-lattice?

I believe so (in both cases, considering them as objects with structure-preserving linear transformations as morphisms) but I don't think I'm up to proving it. *Please help.* If the answer to the first question is "yes," but the second, "no," then does $\mathcal{C}$ contain an object that is *approximately* $\mathscr{L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)}$?

*What do I mean by "approximately $\mathscr{L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)}$"?*

Okay, I'm not sure what I mean, but I guess "such that enough of the salient features of $\mathscr{L^1(\mathbb{R}^k)}$ are reflected" is about right. How close can we get?

---

*This bit can be ignored.*

Furthermore, - and to provide some *extra* motivation for these questions - there seems to be a heavy use of characteristic functions in the theory of Lebesgue Integration, which, to me, calls to mind topoi. I'm not sure why. So, yeah, wouldn't it be cool if we could find a sub-category of the category of vector-lattices (let's say over $\mathbb{R}^k$) that's also a topos, that has an object *a bit like* $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^k)$?

> Does such a thing exist?

Nope: See the first comment! $\ddot\smile$

---

I find these questions interesting in their own right and I hope you agree :)

Comment: The only topos which also supports an additive structure is the degenerate one.

Comment: @ZhenLin So that's the "Futhermore" bit out the window! Thank you! Now, how about the other questions? :)

Comment: The characteristic functions link you're thinking of might be the subobject classifier. That's probably not appropriate in this setting, though.

Comment: I'm finding a lot on "the category of Archemidean vector-lattices" but no (accessible) definition of that category so far.

Comment: [This dissertation (in pdf form)](http://upetd.up.ac.za/thesis/available/etd-02062006-130754/unrestricted/00dissertation.pdf) seems relevant to my previous comment. (It's relatively late where I am, so please excuse me for not reading the related bits in more detail.)

Comment: NB: That pdf is quite large but the relevant bits are right at the beginning. Sorry :/

Comment: @ZhenLin May I goad you into answering the other highlighted questions? Please :) They don't seem as bad as the other one . . .

Comment: Well, am I right? :)

Comment: @Shaun: Can you give a direct link of the pdf?

Comment: Which one, @user170039? They're all direct links.

Comment: @Shaun: The link of the pdf of dissertation. Whenever I click on it, [this page](https://repository.up.ac.za/) opens.

Comment: @user170039: Well, it *is* a direct link, only it must have expired; I checked by scanning the underlying link but not clicking on it. It redirects. Unfortunately, I can't remember what dissertation it was so I can't update it. I'm sorry :/

Comment: @Shaun: Is this by any chance [this dissertation](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf)? Sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: I don't know. I think it is, @user170039, as I've seen it before and it's relevant here. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it's not that dissertation, @user170039, as it's linked to in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712594/104041) to a question of mine, and I know I didn't use that. Thank you anyway :)