# Integrals in analysis and category theory

Tags: category-theory

Are integrals in analysis special cases of [coends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coend) in category theory? They are both seen as *weighted sums*, denoted by $\displaystyle\int $ and share the same formal properties (for example Fubini's Theorem). Also notice that there is a very beautiful reformulation of the Yoneda Lemma
$$F(a) = \int^{p \in I} \mathrm{Hom}(a,p) \otimes F(p)$$
for functors $F : I^{op} \to \mathcal{C}$ into a cocomplete category $\mathcal{C}$ which looks like the equation
$$\mu(A) = \int_{p \in I} \chi_A(p) ~ d \mu(p)$$
for a measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $I$.

Notice that this question is not as silly as it seems: Limits in analysis can be seen as limits in category theory, see  [MO/9951](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9951) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29#Limits_2) (*Topological limits*).

If the measurable space $I$ is discrete, the question is about (infinite) series - are they special cases of coends?

Comment: Every colimit is a coend, namely $\varinjlim F = \int^{i : \mathcal{I}} F i$.

Comment: [I'm pretty sure that what you wrote is the **co**-Yoneda lemma](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma). The Yoneda lemma would be $F(a) = \int_{p \in I} [\hom(p,a), F(p)]$ (with covariant $F : I \to \mathcal{C}$ this time).

Comment: Did you take a look at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/23/12/23-12.pdf ? It does not answer your question about coends, but it might prove useful if you are interested in categorical integration...

Comment: @Najib: These are formally equivalent statements (look at $F^{op}$ etc.).

Comment: Of course, the name is pretty telling :). I simply wanted to point out that it has a different name and interpretation (in terms of presheaves and colimits of representable functors) under this form.

Comment: (Somewhat) related: [«...will instantly recognise this formula as a tropical integral...» @ MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/80719/1556)

Comment: [This is also (somewhat) related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728069/is-this-really-a-categorical-approach-to-integration)

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but it was too long for a comment.

Lawvere "Metric spaces" paper relates the inner and outer measure on a probability space to Kan extensions (which can be written as ends/coends). This is p. 162:

> As an example of the last corollary [see the paper], we could take for $X$ the space of nonnegative step functions of a probability space $S$ and for $Y$ the space of all nonnegative functions with the natural sup metric, and consider as $\varphi$ the elementary integral; thus in general we might call $y\in Y$ $\varphi$-integrable if [a certain right Kan extension, the inner measure] = [a certain left Kan extension, the outer measure].